# Laravel API passport - Unable to login

Tags: php, laravel, http, authentication, laravel-passport

After i register an user using the passport and see the user in database.
i tried to login and i get the message "Unauthorised".
this is my login method:

```
public function login(){
    if(Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])){
        $user = Auth::user();
        $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;
        return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this->successStatus);
    }
    else{
        return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401);
    }
}
```

i also tried to receive the Request in the login method as a parameter and handle it but i still do not login.

[I'm using Postman to perform the request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SG0uR.png)

[update]

i checked that my request() is receiving null

Comment: Also paste your API POST request  here

Comment: you never send a session cookie I guess?

Comment: @FarsheelRahman i already edited my question.

Comment: did you try to send as url encoded the data instead of url params ?

Comment: Did you try with `\Auth`?

Comment: @LeoKelmendi i logged with success now using this "http://memo.dev/api/login?email=test@mail.com&password=123456" but that's not what i want, when i try to write the params in body, the request in the login method returns null

Comment: what are you headers looking like ?

Comment: i didn't know what happend but i tried to do the request as the initial, with the login method like what i publish here and it authenticate with success ... i can't understand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add those parameters in request body as `JSON` data like below

```
{
    "email":"test@mail.com",
    "password":"123456"

}
```

also add `Content-Type:application/json` to your request header.

then need a little bit change in your `login()` method to accept the `JSON` data received

```
public function login(Request $request){

        if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->json('email'), 'password' => $request->json('password')])){
            $user = Auth::user();
            $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;
            return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this->successStatus);
        }
        else{
            return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401);
        }
    }
```

Response:-

```
{
    "success": {
        "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6IjAzZDA1YzRiMmRhNTc3YmQ4ZTliMTRlZjE3MWRlYWIyOTI2NTJjNjg2MDY2ZmU1ZjYzM2ZiZjBjNTc3YTM0MGM1NDUxOTczZTYxZmFjMjIzIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianRpIjoiMDNkMDVjNGIyZGE1NzdiZDhlOWIxNGVmMTcxZGVhYjI5MjY1MmM2ODYwNjZmZTVmNjMzZmJmMGM1NzdhMzQwYzU0NTE5NzNlNjFmYWMyMjMiLCJpYXQiOjE1MTExMDcwNzAsIm5iZiI6MTUxMTEwNzA3MCwiZXhwIjoxNTQyNjQzMDcwLCJzdWIiOiIxIiwic2NvcGVzIjpbXX0.GrFth1I7PnkT7FOSQkkUEl0uc3CddUVEAgMHwFlKIIiC740B-Eu3-73IrYEH-VYXeWrZKP9FaK2lL_QR7wpZXnP20e5q4OoznVg0kqE5DsfsFw8lywUtPF7so4QcxcU3wFUKWGl4nEDTaiAJtU4UJnBcaG6Xj98jqEsGIkY9fboOI2bpbQvWPeI3k6kg1V3zE6M34tI-5s9d691NCprrPtlcBGD0sGsHwaP7Yv6j27MD3qSUboj-2KGZMtPl2ITTbTq8MSX-oJ5z-ASPlugDuF0NN-1Ru6FLW2CzFzAFh1ixVd6o0PnlK1Ep5qO6SN8_xida_lhgVqakArR_QLpyQAk0AuIixKzwnxCAaWfhE6Ljp-8sbhKY3sDawe-g05LOvxiyTgzqKBn9u_qCbkOm7e21eBbt1Pr0JKbu8_Rc5Mun-QnbaQiARs078xQnRfb3UJISluL6mKVdLdxwLeeJy38JJn6a_rm1xj5VLcBEW9sxEGdt4qwEJJML1qWP6KZ4ptJ2svx0ehebYtvDTvByxc9ONLYxSZ5i6X7nZdbgVgD7HrQby_HbvwTqcOiojvJxv3eDz5WMOZv8FSYo4UoDzsgRsSMs4QIeBkeNvstW28XuSoVoxzX_6i6IfQ-tFJ3SJWpyGKYlAnC61Jj5u0slKEneTiDY1pJnFAGIZqyw1_k"
    }
}
```

Request Postman Screenshot:-

[image]

if you got any doubt on this, just comment below

Answer (score 0):

In my case there is password stored without hash or bcypt in laravel, if password stored in hash then Auth::attempt() will work.